Composer installer-paths not being respected
I am using the johnpbloch/wordpress-project composer template for my Wordperss project. In this project, we are using a theme downloaded from the internet that is not distributed by composer. I therefore need to have this theme with the rest of the files, but I don't want it to be easily editable - because we should not modify it.
I made that theme a composer artifact. To make sure it would be put in the right folder, I set its type to "wordpress-theme" in its composer.json before zipping it.
Here is the composer.json I created for the theme in question (/composer/artifacts/Enfold.zip/composer.json):
{
    "name": "wpackagist-theme/enfold",
    "type": "wordpress-theme",
    "version": "4.5.7",
    "require": {}
}

Here is my entire composer.json for the project (/composer.json):
{
    "name": "johnpbloch/wordpress-project",
    "description": "An out-of-the-box composer-powered WordPress package inspired by Mark Jaquith's WordPress Skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
        },
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "./composer/artifacts/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4 || ^8.0",
        "illuminate/support": "^8.83",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress-core": "@stable",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer": "^2.0",
        "johnpbloch/wp-cli-phar": "^2.6",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.5",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4",
        "wpackagist-theme/enfold": "^4.5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "JohnPBloch\\WordPressProject\\Scripts\\": "./scripts"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "wordpress-install-dir": "public/wp",
        "installer-paths": {
            "public/content/plugins/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-plugin"
            ],
            "public/content/mu-plugins/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-muplugin"
            ],
            "public/content/themes/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-theme"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer": true
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "JohnPBloch\\WordPressProject\\Scripts\\GenerateKeysAndSalts::run"
        ]
    }
}

As I understand it, it should be installed in /public/content/themes/, but it is not. Whether I just composer install the whole project, composer update or composer update wpackagist-theme/enfold, it always goes in /vendor/.
What am I doing wrong?
